# Wpf Realtime DataBinding To Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, observablecollection

I want to bind data (1000 record per second, i mean 25 records per 25 milisecond) to a listview and it must be ordered descending by datetime.

I have used observable collection. When i get data from the source (e.g socket), i am adding to my collection by inserting the model at the zero index of observable collection.

```
 observableCollection.Insert(0, model);
```

It is working no problem but it is using %30 cpu (intel i5). And if i open these windows 10 times, my application is getting slower. I am using virtualizing properties.
If i don't set the itemsource of the listview, cpu usage is about %0.

This is my listview:

```
 <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"   Name="listView" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Grid.Column="0"   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  ItemsSource="{Binding observableCollection}">
  <ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel></VirtualizingStackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemsPanel>
  <ListView.View>

    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" Width="75"  Header="Id" />
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}" Width="175"  Header="Time"  />
      <!-- Ten more columns -->
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Is it correct to use listview?

How can i increase the performance?

Is there any other techniques to do this?

Comment: Ignoring the refresh problem for a moment, are you really expecting users to scroll through that much data looking for something? I'd argue that even the visible rows at the top would be changing too quickly for someone to "read" what's in them. Might an alternate UI be a better approach? For example, writing the data into some kind of log file and providing users with a search dialog.

Comment: No, users should use scrolling

Comment: That's unfortunate. You've probably already realised that the `ObservableCollection` and `ItemsControl` binding approach will not cope with this volume of data refreshing at this speed. Also you are inserting items at the top of the list, not the bottom, which AFAIK will cause the items control to refresh *all* of its containers. If those are your UI constraints then I would suggest abandoning the items control and binding altogether, writing your own custom control and creating the visuals via code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

The INotifyCollectionChanged event of ObservableCollection is the bottleneck. Try to build your result list first, then to create an ObservableCollection from your list, and then assign the ObservableCollection to the ItemsSource of your control.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a fake scroll bar by only adding the top 100 items to the list box but setting the maximum and value of a separate scroll bar to the actual data size and position. This requires more code to keep the scroll bar and list box in sync.

The amount of data and the number of updates is just too much and faking a long list might be the only solution.